# Rails validations failing when logged in as admin user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have the following create action in my Rails 3 controller:

```
def create
    @registration = Registration.new(params[:registration])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @registration.save
        if @registration.orientation != nil #TODO replace this with an online? method
          format.html { render "scheduling_text.html.erb" }
          format.json { render json: @registration, status: :created, location: @registration }
          NsoMailer.registration_email(@registration).deliver
        else
          format.html { render "online_scheduling_text.html.erb" }
          format.json { render json: @registration, status: :created, location: @registration }
          NsoMailer.online_registration_email(@registration).deliver
        end
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" } 
        format.json { render json: @registration.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity } 
      end
    end
  end
```

I have my own authentication in place, and when I am not logged into the app my validations work as they should. That is to say I make it inside the respond_to block of the code above. However, as an authenticated user if I try and submit this form, my validations fail with this error...

```
Started POST "/registrations" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-11 09:52:13 -0400
Processing by RegistrationsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PJMFr2FYTYszVndofuZZTaFTmwN8C/41oc6h7ldqfKA=", "registration"=>{"orientation_id"=>"3", "first_name"=>"", "last_name"=>"", "email"=>"", "student_id"=>"", "phone"=>"", "program"=>""}, "commit"=>"Register"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.0ms)  rollback transaction
  Rendered registrations/_form.html.erb (6.4ms)
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered registrations/new.html.erb within layouts/application (8.4ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 16ms

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:controller=>"registrations"}):
  app/views/registrations/new.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_registrations_new_html_erb__773571217_97879480'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in create'
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:52:in `create'


  Rendered /home/johnmlocklear/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/gems/actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (0.5ms)
```

This seems to has something to do with routing? Just as an aside my routes look like...

```
/orientations/3/registrations/new
```

when the form initially loads, and after validation fails the route is...

```
/registrations
```

...with hidden values for the orientation_id. Not sure what that would have to do with a user be logged in. Also notice in the error there is a line that reloads the user. I don't see that when I'm not logged in, so that could also be part of the issue.

Any help appreciated!

## EDIT

here is app/views/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<h1>Register for New Student Orientation</h1>

<%= render 'form' %>

<%= link_to 'Back', orientations_path %>

<% if current_user %>
  </br>
  <%= link_to 'View Registrations', orientation_registrations_path %>
<%end%>
```

Here is the orientation_registrations routes...

```
orientation_registrations GET    /orientations/:orientation_id/registrations(.:format)          registrations#index
                          POST   /orientations/:orientation_id/registrations(.:format)          registrations#create
```

Comment: Can you post your form.

Comment: What is on line 9 of `app/views/registrations/new.html.erb`?  As that is where the error is, I assumed it you be in your form but I can't see anything

Comment: Baloo, I just added the new template above. Line 9 is the link to View Registrations line. Sure enough that is the issue. When I remove that line the validations work for authenticated users. That makes since why it worked when I was logged out because of the if current_user line. Now why does it fail?

Comment: What is in your routes?  That looks like you have a nested route, which you would need to pass a orientation id to.

Comment: Just added those routes above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in an orientation id. `:orientation_id` in the path is the parameter rails is expecting

Rather than

```
<%= link_to 'View Registrations', orientation_registrations_path %>
```

You need something like

```
<%= link_to 'View Registrations', orientation_registrations_path( @registration.orientation) if @registration.orientation %>
```

Your controller handles that orientation might be nil, but your view code for having a current user assumes it's there.